# Magento Patch 6788 Installation error

Tags: php, magento, ssh, patch

I am trying to install magento patch 6788 form ssh.
but when i run command

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-59-27.sh
```

i am getting this error

```
  Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
    ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git .htaccess .htaccess
|index 60e1795..aca7f55 100644
|--- .htaccess
|+++ .htaccess
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file .htaccess.sample
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 287 (offset -7 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej
```

and please give me some tips to upgrade magento current version from ssh 
Please Help to fix that

Answer (score 0):

If you have not changed the file, just rename and replace the Admin.php of your distribution version.

Comment: admin.php can you tell me the location of that file?

Comment: @KaranAdhikari app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php